# How to use case statements to return different pulls in sql?

Tags: sql, presto, apache-zeppelin

I am working in presto SQL and trying to make it so that I can do different select statements depending on a user input. My current code structure looks something like this:

```
SELECT (case when input in ('A', 'B', 'C') then (SELECT * from table1)
             when input in ('D', 'E', 'F') then (SELECT * from table2)
             when input in ('G', 'H', 'I') then (SELECT * from table3)
             ...
        end)
```

When I do this, I get an error saying I cannot return a subquery with multiple columns. Is there a way to accomplish separate select statements either using this structure or another method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the tables have the same columns, use `union all`:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where input in ('A', B', 'C')
union all
select t.*
from table2 t
where input in ('D', E', 'F')
union all
. . .
```